# Error: Cannot find symbol showing up Java Beginner

Tags: java, jcreator

I'm attempting to create a program that selects a random word from a file and outputs the correct number of spaces depending on the length of the word. For example, if the word is smart, the program outputs _ _ _ _ _. This is the program:

```
    import java.util.*;
    import java.io.*;
    public class Selection {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String[] words = new String[100];
        Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileReader("words.txt"));
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                words[i] = in.next();
        Random r = new Random();
        int selected = r.nextInt[100];
        String sWord = words[selected];

        for (int j = 0; j < sWord.length(); j++)
                System.out.printf("_");

        in.close();
}
}
```

And this is the error:

```
    java:18: error: cannot find symbol
    int selected = r.nextInt[100];
                    ^
    symbol:   variable nextInt
    location: variable r of type Random
    1 error
```

Any help in understanding what I didn't do correctly would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Simply change your code to this: `int selected = r.nextInt(100);`

Answer (score 3):

```
 int selected = r.nextInt[100];// use () r.nextInt(num);
```

Comment: Please let the OP know why.

Comment: Like because it's a method not an array.

Answer (score 1):

```
int selected = r.nextInt[100];
```

Your problem is here, you are trying to access the variable nextInt like an array, but it is a function.

The correct way to do this is:

```
int selected = r.nextInt(100);
```

You use the parentheses because you are passing the value 100 as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for some reasons the format here doesnt work for me

You have

> ```
> int selected = r.nextInt[100];
> ```

the code should be

> ```
> int selected = r.nextInt(100);
> ```

The reason being this is you use [] for array, () to call a method on an object.

For example,
if you want to create an array, you do

> int[] arr = new int[100]; // created an array with enough storage to hold 100 int

the following would fail

> ```
> int() arr = new int(arr); // fail!
> ```

On the other hand,
if you do

> ```
> Random r = new Random(); // it works!
> ```

but the following would fail

> ```
> Random r = new Random[]; // fail!
> ```